# Fixed width flat file column addition via Excel or Notepad++

Tags: excel, notepad++, flat-file, fixed-width

I have a fixed width flat file with n columns. I need to add a new column at the end that is a concatenation of some of the columns.
Eg.

```
0624 11011 LOCA   
0624 11031 LOCC   
0624 11041 LOCB
```

turns into

```
0624 11011 LOCA 0624LOCA-ABC  
0624 11031 LOCC 0624LOCC-ABC  
0624 11041 LOCB 0624LOCB-ABC
```

I imported file files as text in Excel and was able to generate the column quickly using the concatenate function. 
But I now need to generate it as the flat file again. How do I do this? 
Is there a feature in Excel to allow me to generate the sheet as a flat file with spaces. Or can I "transfer" the column to the same file in Notepad++.
I am looking for a handy keyboard option, else I have to go to SQL.

Comment: Have you considered writing the data to an array, then writing from the array to a text file? I have had good success using this method of getting data from Excel to a flat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, click `Save as`, and choose the "save as type:"  "Formatted Text (space delimited)".

Alternative, in Notepad++, if they are fixed width to start with, use Column Copy/Paste to build the extra column.  (Hold Left <kbd>ALT</kbd> down while highlighting 1 column, <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> then put cursor at end of first line, add a few spaces, click <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>.  Repeat for 2nd column ;)

If you need to add additional text to all columns (ie hyphen seperating them), Use the Left `ALT` trick again to highlight a zero width selection across all rows, then just type .. it'll mirror the typing for all rows :)

If you're file is significantly larger, however, I'd stick with Excel, or try Toto's Regular Expression replace ;)

Comment: Thanks, saving the file in Excel as 'Formatted text' did not preserve the spaces when I checked the saved file. However, the Notepad++ option of Copying the entire specific column individually, pasting, mirroring common text and patching 'em up did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

With Npp, I'd do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `((\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+))`
- Repace with: `$1 $2$3-ABC`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure you have checked `Regular Expression`.

I assume that the delimiter is one space.

Comment: Thanks, this was a neat trick. As it turned out though, some of the columns (17 in all) had spaces in them, and intermittently so, hence I couldn't get a fix on a common regex that would work on all lines.